# How did the media know the method Batman used to catch the Joker?

Tags: dc, powerless-tv

At the end of the pilot episode of Powerless, the media reports the Joker was caught

> using a device which could smell Joker's odor and alert Batman to his presence. The same device just invented at Wayne Security.

The thing is, Batman isn't known for his press conferences. How did the media know the exact nature of how Batman caught the joker?

Comment: Gosh darnit, Robin!  Loose lips sink ships! *- Batman, the next day.*

Comment: "Gosh, Batman - Remember this leather thong? It still has your teeth marks in it!"

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the screenshot below, it's the police who're apprehending the Joker, not Batman. Presumably Batman has chosen to explain to his contact in the Gotham PD (probably Commissioner Gordon) how he's able to suddenly track him. The police would be in a position to share that information with the press.

[image]

That being said, it's not like he hasn't shared info (and a heck of a lot more) with [the press in Gotham city](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Vicki_Vale) before now.